# Why was ffmpeg removed from Debian?

Tags: debian, ffmpeg

Currently, `ffmpeg` is missing from APT packages when using the stable versions of Debian and Ubuntu.

There are numerous resources ([example from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/286675/42345), another one [from Debian's documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/ffmpeg) and [the one from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/432542/229568)) which explain how to install it in a different (and more complex) way than a simple `apt-get install ffmpeg`.

What I wonder is why the package is not there in the first place?

From what I understood, `avconv` is a fork of `ffmpeg` and is a *de facto* standard for Debian similar distributions. Meanwhile, `ffmpeg` is not abandoned: [the website](https://ffmpeg.org/) mentions no intention to close the project in profit of `avconv`, despite the fact that the leader of `ffmpeg` [left the project](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-July/176489.html).

So:

- Why `ffmpeg` was plainly removed from APT packages, instead of keeping it and simply adding `avconv`?
- Is there a reason (other than the fact that it became more difficult to install `ffmpeg`) to stop using it?

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/607591/

Comment: I can't comment specifically why it was removed from `apt`, however the `Libav` fork of `FFmpeg` (not to mention its ensuing confusion) is well-documented elsewhere: [Fork from FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libav#Fork_from_FFmpeg).

Comment: You may find the answers to this question useful: [What are the differences and similarities between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv)

Comment: @jordanm: indeed, among with the two other comments, that helps a lot (the quote *“the Debian developer who maintained ffmpeg was part of the group that created the fork, so he naturally pulled the distribution along for the ride”* alone answers my question). Do you want to promote your comment to an answer, including relevant quotes of the article?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Why *was* `ffmpeg` not available in the repo?

For some time there was a so-called "`ffmpeg`" available after Debian switched to Libav, but it was not from FFmpeg. This can probably be explained best with a a rough timeline of what happened:

1. Libav split from FFmpeg and kept the `ffmpeg` binary name (it also kept the names of the libraries, and the "libav" name was already being used by FFmpeg as a collective noun for the libraries: libavcodec, libavformat, libavutils, etc.).
2. The Debian ffmpeg package maintainer at the time, a member of the Libav fork, switched Debian to use Libav.
3. Libav eventually deprecated/renamed their `ffmpeg` to `avconv`, then eventually removed the counterfeit "`ffmpeg`", but some downstream users such as Ubuntu kept the old, fake "`ffmpeg`" for "compatibility and transitional" reasons for some time.
4. Debian/Ubuntu eventually removed the buggy, old, dead, fake "`ffmpeg`".
5. FFmpeg returns in [Debian stable](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/ffmpeg) (jessie-backports) and [Ubuntu Vivid 15.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ffmpeg).
6. Debian/Ubuntu drops Libav.

You're currently between steps 4 and 5. Updating to a newer release of your distro will allow you to install the real `ffmpeg` from the repository.

## Is there a reason to stop using `ffmpeg`?

[FFmpeg development is very active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=shortlog;h=HEAD), and now that Libav has lost its major downstream users I think you can ask this question about `avconv` instead.

## Other stuff

> ...the leader of the FFmpeg left the project.

Michael Niedermayer is still [quite active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=search;h=HEAD;s=Michael%20Niedermayer;st=author). He just got tired of some of the admin duties and politics and resigned as leader. Also, it was a gesture to Libav developers as a potential step for reunification with Libav developers.